# What do I need to add, to ask my Python 3 program to check if the input is in ascending or descending order?

Tags: python

I need to make my program to check whether the input is in ascending order on in descending order. It works already, however not correctly, I believe I need to add something more? I am very new to programming.

Here is my code :

```
b = 0
last = int(input()) 

finished= False
while not finished:
  new = int(input())
  if new == -1:
    finished = True
  elif last == -1:
    finished = True
  elif new > last :
    b = 1
  elif new <= last:
    b = 2
  last = new

if b == 1:
  print ('yes')
elif b == 2:
  print ('no')
```

Comment: It would be simpler to put all the inputs into a list, and operate on that list

Comment: can you please provide some input and output you will get? it will be easy for us to understand what you need

Comment: Why do you ask for two inputs at once? Doing this, you're also rewriting the data in `last`.

Comment: @Exprator . For example if a input 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7.  The program will has to output "Yes"
If input 1, 2 , 3 , 4 ,5 , 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 . The program has to output 'no'

Comment: @ForceBru, thank you , changed that now!

Comment: but bro you are taking only 2 inputs? you can only check for 2 numbers

Comment: @Exprator it's in a while loop

Comment: @Exprator, yes thats the problem , somehow I need to check wether the next input( after new input) will be greater than the new input

Comment: @Dwaxe, I need to to this trough while loop. 
but thank you for your advice

Comment: @StefanShakhazizyan, you should consider the value of `b` before assigning to it. So, if the first two numbers were in ascending order, but the next one doesn't fit that pattern, your code'll switch to "descending order", which won't be true.

Comment: @ForceBru , could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the values of `b`:

```
b = 0
last = int(input()) 

while True:
    new = int(input())
    if (new == -1) or (last == -1):
        break
    elif new > last :
        if b == 2: # this has been descending until now
            b = 0 # neither ascending nor descending
            break
        b = 1
    elif new < last:
        if b == 1: # this has been ascending until now
            b = 0
            break
        b = 2
    else: # when two adjacent values are equal, this order is neither ascending, nor descending
        b = 0
        break
    last = new

if not b:
    print("Neither ascending, nor descending")
elif b == 1:
    print ('ascending')
elif b == 2:
    print ('descending')
else:
    print("This is odd, we shouldn't have got here...")
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped !

Answer (score 0):

This will continue asking the user for inputs until it receives a `-1` as input. If there's a single input that makes the list in descending order, it will print `'no'` at the end of the loop (when the user inputs `-1`).

```
b = 0
last = int(input('Last: ')) 

while True:
  new = int(input('New: '))     
  if new == -1 or last == -1:
      break
  elif new <= last:
    b = 2
  last = new

if b == 2:
  print ('no')
else:
  print ('yes')
```